# FindMaximum works on desktop but not on laptop

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a simple code to find maximum as follows.

```
myfunc = {-1 + 2/(1 + d), 1/2 (-1 + 1/d), 1 - d, 1 + 1/(-2 + d), 
   1 - d, 1 - d, -1 + 1/d, -1 + 1/d, 1/(1 + d), 1/(2 d), 1/d, 1/d, d/(
   1 - d)};
FindMaximum[{##, 0 <= d <= 1}, d] & /@ myfunc
```

It works well on my desktop and the result is:

```
{{1., {d -> 0.}}, {\[Infinity], {d -> 0.}}, {1., {d -> 
    0.}}, {0.5, {d -> 0.}}, {1., {d -> 0.}}, {1., {d -> 
    0.}}, {\[Infinity], {d -> 0.}}, {\[Infinity], {d -> 
    0.}}, {1., {d -> 0.}}, {\[Infinity], {d -> 
    0.}}, {\[Infinity], {d -> 0.}}, {\[Infinity], {d -> 
    0.}}, {\[Infinity], {d -> 1.}}}
```

However, I got error with `$Failed` when I ran it on my laptop.

```
{{1., {d -> 3.54538*10^-8}}, {-$Failed, {d -> 0.}}, {1., {d -> 
    0.}}, {0.5, {d -> 0.}}, {1., {d -> 0.}}, {1., {d -> 
    0.}}, {-$Failed, {d -> 0.}}, {-$Failed, {d -> 0.}}, {1., {d -> 
    0.}}, {\[Infinity], {d -> Indeterminate}}, {\[Infinity], {d -> 
    0.}}, {\[Infinity], {d -> 0.}}, {\[Infinity], {d -> 
    Indeterminate}}}
```

Why does this happen? How can I solve this?

Comment: Different versions of MMA on each? I get the last result (plus a bunch of warnings) on my Win10-64 laptop running MMA 12.0

Comment: My desktop is `12.2.0.0` while it's `12.0.0.0` on my laptop with both Win10-64.

Comment: Well, there you go then. Update the laptop to the newer version, or use the cloud version on the laptop if you have access to it. Even the 12.2 version spits out a number of warnings though. It is always best to include any errors or warnings in the description of your problem.

Comment: In 12.2.0.0 on Windows 10Pro I obtained "FindMaximum::ubndf: The feasible region includes points where the objective function is singular. The returned solution lies on the singularity.f" and the first output.

Comment: Downloading... What is better, Mathematica for Sites  or Mathematica for Students for Sites?

Comment: @anhnha I think MMA for students may have some limitation although I am not completely sure of the differences. If you have access to both, go for the "MMA for sites"; in my understanding that's the "standard" version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`FindMaximum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html) "searches for a local maximum" it should generally be used only when [`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html) is unable to find the maximum.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

myfunc = {-1 + 2/(1 + d), 1/2 (-1 + 1/d), 1 - d, 1 + 1/(-2 + d), 1 - d, 
    1 - d, -1 + 1/d, -1 + 1/d, 1/(1 + d), 1/(2 d), 1/d, 1/d, d/(1 - d)} // 
   DeleteDuplicates;

Off[Maximize::natt]

{#, Maximize[{#, 0 <= d <= 1}, d]} & /@ myfunc // Grid
```

[image]